# Drop-down list "View engine" is missing in View create dialog in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a ASP.NET MVC 4 project and found that the drop-down "View engine" list is missing in the view creation dialog. But I need it to create a aspx page to output a report using a ReportViewer component.
What am I missing? Or how else can I force MVC 4 to render aspx?

Comment: Can you share your code and tell us what you are trying to do and what issue you are facing?

Comment: what version of VS do you have?

Comment: Does your project already contain **aspx** pages, or was it built using **Razor** pages? If the latter is true then you are mixing View Engines, which could be a royal headache, although this may guide you: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to do something like what's shown to [that guy's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTmg3bH-8tc&t=511s). I created a [repository on github](https://github.com/r00xus/TestReportAspx). There are two projects. TestReportAspx using Webforms and there everything works. TestReportMvc using MVC4. And it does not work :(